# Is there a way to use the day of year as an input format for the date command?

Tags: linux, date

Using the command

```
$ date +%j
```

gives an output of the day of the year (001-366).
However I need to use the day of the current year as an input format i.e.

```
$ date --date='066 day'  +%F
```

Which for year 2021 I would expect `2021-03-07` as the output. Instead I get `2021-05-13`. Does anyone know what is going on and if there is a way to get what I want using `date`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get the 66th day of the year with GNU `date`:

```
$ date --date='jan 1 + 65 days' +%F
2021-03-07
```

or

```
$ date --date='dec 31 last year + 66 days' +%F
2021-03-07
```

With `date --date='066 day' +%F` you get the date 66 days from today.  On the 8th of March, this happens to be the 13th of May.

---

The above uses GNU `date`.  On OpenBSD (not that you asked, but anyway), you could do something like the following:

```
$ date -u -r "$(( $(date -ju -f %m%d 0101 +%s) + 65*86400 ))" +%F
2021-03-07
```

which would be somewhat similar to the first GNU `date` command above in that it adds some time from January 1st.

Comment: Yes it is GNU date I am using.

Comment: I think that the OpenBSD code is wrong in Southern hemisphere timezones with daylight savings time: it skips the day of the DST switch, since 86400 seconds after the start of that day, it's still the same day at 23:00. `+ $n days` with GNU date calculates in calendar days, so its problem is even more subtle: it doesn't handle day skips correctly, e.g. [Tokelau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokelau#Time_zone): `TZ=Pacific/Fakaofo date -d '28 December 2011 + 2 days'` → Dec 31. The fix is easy: always use `TZ=UTC0` for date calculations. @Brennan

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Fixed by using `-u` with both `date` invocations. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I propose this option: if for example you want to know the date of the 80th day:

```bsh
# take the number of day today
$ n=$(date +%j)
# set some number of days you want to know the date
$ t=80
# subtract the 'n', and add the 't'
$ date -d "-$n day +$t day" %F
2021-03-21
```

---

Adapted to your example:

```bsh
$ n=$(date +%j)
$ t=66
$ date -d "-$n day +$t day" %F
2021-03-07
```

Comment: That would work for me as well, thanks. Kusalananda's answer is more intuitive for me at least. I tried to upvote your answer anyways but it wouldn't let me because of my rep.

Comment: @Brennan don't worry! Thanks for your feedback. :) gave you +1.

Comment: @Brennan You should now have enough reps. to upvote, if you wish to do so. :-)

Comment: `+ $n days` with GNU date calculates in calendar days, so it mostly avoids DST issues, but it doesn't handle day skips correctly, e.g. [Tokelau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokelau#Time_zone): `TZ=Pacific/Fakaofo date -d '28 December 2011 + 2 days'`. The fix is easy: always use `TZ=UTC0` for date calculations.

Comment: Wow.  Day skip!  And I thought I knew a lot about time zones.